# Rest of divison of $A(x)B(x)$ by $C(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$A(x) , B(x) , C(x) , R_1(x) $ and $R_2(x)$ are polynomials.

Consider $R_1(x) := rem(A(x),C(x)) $ and $R_2(x) := rem(B(x),C(x))$ .

Is it true that $rem(A(x)B(x) \ ,\  C(x)) = rem(R_1(x)R_2(x) \  , \ C(x))$ ? If it's true prove it.

My try : I did it in general form but didn't get any result.

Comment: $A=CQ_1+R_1$ and $B=CQ_2+R_2 \implies AB=C(Q_1B+R_1Q_2)+R_1R_2$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes but it isn't same as $rem(A(x)B(x) \ ,\  C(x)) = rem(R_1(x)R_2(x) \  , \ C(x))$

Comment: Related, isn't it?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes , it is related but I can't deduct it from your expression. If you can prove it , please write it

Comment: @JonasMeyer Why we can't say "$rem(A(x)B(x) \ ,\  C(x)) = R_1(x)R_2(x)$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are polynomials such that $C$ divides $P_1-P_2$, then $P_1$ and $P_2$ have the same remainder when dividing by $C$.

To see this, we assume $P_1-P_2=CP$ for some polynomial $P$, and with polynomial division obtain $P_1=Cq_1+r_1$, $P_2=Cq_2+r_2$.  Then $P_1-P_2=C(q_1-q_2)+r_1-r_2$.  From $CP=C(q_1-q_2)+r_1-r_2$ we can conclude that $r_1-r_2$ is a multiple of $C$, which implies that $r_1-r_2=0$ (because $r_1-r_2$ can't have degree as large as $C$).

This applies with $P_1=AB$ and $P_2=R_1R_2$ because if polynomial division yields $A  =CQ_1+R_1$ and $B=CQ_2+R_2$, then $AB-R_1R_2=C(Q_1B+R_1Q_2)$.

---

A question I see added in a comment is, why can't we say that the remainder of $AB$ when dividing by $C$ equals $R_1R_2$?  The reason is that $R_1R_2$ might have degree as large or larger than $C$.  Example: $A=B=x^2+x$, $C=x^2$, $R_1R_2=x^2$, but the remainder of $AB$ when dividing by $C$ is $0$.

Comment: Can you explain first part of your answer ?

Comment: @S.H.W. Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: What do you mean by "If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are polynomials such that $C$ divides $P_1-P_2$ , then $P_1$ and $P_2$ have the same remainder when dividing by $C$" ?

Comment: @S.H.W. I'm having a hard time guessing which part of that statement is unclear, or I'd try to helpfully reword it.  The following paragraph, which provides a proof, also provides more detailed context of what is being asserted.  I'll just expand some: It's saying that if $P_1-P_2$ is a multiple of $C$, which means $P_1-P_2=CP$ for some polynomial $P$, then $P_1$ and $P_2$ give the same remainder when dividing by $C$, which means if $P_1=Cq_1+r_1$ and $P_2=Cq_2+r_2$ is the result of poly long division, then $r_1=r_2$.  Note $P_1=CP+P_2$, just like $AB=C(Q_1B+R_1Q_2)+R_1R_2$.

Comment: The latter equation is the motivation for stating and proving the more general result.

Comment: Is $C$ a number ?

Comment: No, every letter symbol I wrote is a polynomial. Read $A$ as $A(x)$, $B$ as $B(x)$, $C$ as $C(x)$, etc.  Since only polynomials were used I had no need to distinguish different types of objects with the "$x$", and I wanted to save typing and have a less cluttered answer. E.g., notice in the example at the end of the answer that $C=x^2$.

Comment: Every thing is awesome and your answer is beautiful but when we say $P_1 - P_2 = CP$ is it in general ? I think it is not true for all $P_1$ and $P_2$

Comment: @S.H.W: The statement at the beginning is an implication: If the hypothesis holds, then the conclusion holds.  It is totally general *conditional* on whether the hypothesis that $P_1-P_2=CP$ holds for some polynomial $P$.  If that is the case, then necessarily $P_1$ and $P_2$ give the same remainder.  Now it can be applied to each $P_1$ and $P_2$ that do satisfy the hypothesis, and this holds for $P_1=AB$ and $P_2=R_1R_2$.

Comment: Okay , Thanks a lot